# Finding 2 nonabelian, nonisomorphic groups of order 225

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory, semidirect-product

I need to find 2 nonabelian, nonisomorphic groups of order 225. Here's what I have so far:

Let $G$ be a group of order 225.

By Sylow's theorems, we have that $G$ contains $P_{25}$ and $P_{9}$, subgroups of order $25$ and $9$, respectively. It's easy to see that $n_5 = 1$ and, so, $P_{25}$ is normal in $G$. Therefore, $G = P_{25}P_9$, since $P_{25} \cap P_9 = \{1\}$.

Therefore, $G \simeq P_{25} \rtimes_{\varphi} P_9$ for some $\varphi: P_9 \rightarrow \text{Aut}(P_{25})$. Since $P_{25}$ and $P_9$ are both abelian, we need $\varphi$ to be non-trivial.

Now, $P_{25}$ cannot be cyclic (because that would make $G$ abelian), and so, $P_{25} = \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. We know that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}) = GL(2,5)$ which has order $480$, and so, $|\varphi(P_9)| = 1$ or $3$ and, since we need $\varphi$ non trivial, we have $|\varphi(P_9)| = 3$.

Now, we have two choices (upto isomorphism) for $P_9$, $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$. I figure finding such a $\varphi$ for each of these choices will give me what I need.

However, I get stuck here. I tried to find an element of order $3$ in $GL(2,5)$ (for the case where $P_9$ is the cyclic group), but I'm not sure how to do this easily. I'm not really sure how to proceed when $P_9 = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ either.

Comment: Suppose you find an element s of order 3. In the first $ P_9$  case, you can send the generator to $s$. In the second, you can send $(1, 0)$ to $s$. Finding that element may take a little cleverness, though.

Comment: Finding that element is exactly where I am stuck haha

Comment: I can't follow your logic when you say $P_{25}$ and $P_9$ are both cyclic then the next line you say that $P_{25}$ cannot be cyclic. Can you clarify what you mean by those lines and what's your idea behind this approach?

Comment: The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} -1&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ has order 3 over any field.

Comment: @stressed-out oops, I meant $P_{25}$ and $P_9$ are both abelian, since they have order of the form $p^2, p$ prime. If $P_{25}$ is cyclic, it forces $\varphi$ to be trivial (since $|\text{Aut}(C_{25})| = 20$ and $\gcd(9,20) = 1$), which forces $G$ to be abelian.

Comment: @Dane Nice! Is there some kind of general approach I can use to find matrices of required order, for other questions like this?

Comment: In general, I'm not sure. This case is especially nice because it is 2 by 2. Being of order 3 means the matrix satisfies $(x^3-1)/(x-1) = x^2+x+1$. This is the companion matrix.

Comment: Since you're working over a finite field, you could also just list off the elements of the group (computers are nice for this kind of thing). Apparently there are 20 elements of GL(2,5) of order 3.

Comment: Well...you DID say "I'm not sure how to proceed when $P_9 = ...$ either." I was addressing that part, not the "find an element of order 3".